# Printing an information nested in PostgreSQL json data

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

The following PostgreSQL query produces an output in json format.

```
SELECT exampleColumn::jsonb FROM public."MyTable"
```

The output is as follows:

```
[
   {
      "testSettings":{
         "www.test1.com":{
            "IpAddress":[
               {
                  "ipv4Addr":"192.168.0.1",
                  "myId":"myIdExample"
               }
            ]
         },
         "www.try3.com":{
            "IpAddress":[
               {
                  "ipv4Addr":"192.168.0.5",
                  "myId":"myIdExample"
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      "testSettings":{
         "www.test6.com":{
            "IpAddress":[
               {
                  "ipv4Addr":"192.168.0.7",
                  "myId":"myIdExample"
               }
            ]
         },
         "www.try8.com":{
            "IpAddress":[
               {
                  "ipv4Addr":"192.168.0.4",
                  "myId":"myIdExample"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
]
```

I'm aware that testSettings is not unique. However, values starting with 'www' may or may not be unique.

I want to get an output like this using this data:

```
| website           | ipv4Addr      |
|---------------    |-------------  |
| www.test1.com     | 192.168.0.1   |
| www.try3.com      | 192.168.0.5   |
| www.test6.com     | 192.168.0.7   |
| www.try8.com      | 192.168.0.4   |
```

I tried to use the example below for this. However, when I typed a query as

```
SELECT exampleColumn ::jsonb 
FROM public."MyTable" in values()

WITH c(j) AS (
  values(SELECT exampleColumn ::json 
         FROM public."MyTable")
)
SELECT j->jsonb_object_keys(j)->>'www*' 
FROM public."MyTable";
```

I got an error.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48923352

It would be easier if the website names were the same. What could be our solutions for this issue? Thank you.

Comment: My approach would be to redesign the database to use a more relational data model, which would make the task simple. Sorry, I know that this isn't helpful...

Comment: That's non-standard JSON to begin with because your first (and only) array element contains the same key twice. `jsonb` will remove duplicate keys, so the second `testSettings` element will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

The sample data you provided is not a standard JSON, there are duplicate keys. Assuming you're fixing that, you can get the website and its IP address using the below query.

```
SELECT KEY AS website,
              (value->'IpAddress'->0->>'ipv4Addr') AS ipv4Addr
FROM my_table,
     jsonb_each(example_column->0->'testSettings')
WHERE value->'IpAddress'->0->>'ipv4Addr' IS NOT NULL;
```